# File_exists if statement not failing

Tags: php

So I have this If statement that is supposed to check if the file exist and if it fail it should show a default file but the else is not triggering instead it shows "upload//"

```
    if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/uploads/".$photo['album_id'].'/'.
$photo['photo_filename']) == TRUE) {
//gets image if it exist, this part works
        $imgsrc .= "../uploads/".$photo['album_id'].'/'.$photo['photo_filename'];
    } else {
//gets a default image if it doesn't exist, this doesn't work
       $imgsrc .='../uploads/45/image.jpg"';
    }
```

So what happens is either the file name shows from the first part of the if state or "uploads//" shows but what does not show is the else part "../uploads/45/image.jpg". So it looks like it isn't failing.

Comment: What do you mean with: "does not work"? Is the else switch never triggered? Is the image not being displayed correctly? Please provide some more information.

Comment: You made a quote mistake:

    $imgsrc .='../uploads/45/image.jpg"';

Should be:

    $imgsrc .= '../uploads/45/image.jpg';

Comment: Well it is supposed to display a default image if it fails but that is not happening. It shows uploads// instead  of a default. The actual file from the first part of the if statement works fine

Comment: So the else does get triggered when the file does not exist?

Comment: Ya else isn't even triggering it just shows "upload//"  from the first part

Comment: Because your photo data is empty and ( surprise ) the document root _does_ exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the php manual for `file_exists`

> Returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists; FALSE otherwise.

to make sure that the file exist:

```
$filename = "/uploads/".$photo['album_id'].'/'.$photo['photo_filename'];

$filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename;

if(file_exists($filepath) && is_file($filepath)){
 $imgsrc = '..'.$filename;
}
else{
 $imgsrc .='../uploads/45/image.jpg';
}
```

And for `file_exists` you don't need to `== true`. you can just `if(file_exists($filepath))`.

Answer (score 0):

try this condition:

```
 $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/uploads/".$photo['album_id'].'/'.$photo['photo_filename'];    
    if(file_exists($file) && !is_dir($file))
```